How to skip a package-level example in Go?
I have a package level example which I would like to skip running if an environmental variable is not provided. If I just return from it, then output does not match the expected output and when it runs as a test, the test fails.
func Example() {
    if os.Getenv("API_KEY") == "" {
        return
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    output, err := api.Call(ctx, os.Getenv("API_KEY"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(output)

    // Output:
    // 42
}


You cannot skip an example. Examples must be runnable. If the "example" depends on smth make it a unit/untegration test.

You can write Examples, and some IDEs will display these cases.
If you omit the final // Output: in the end of Example, then this example is allowed to not be executed.
If you want to verify your tests, you can write separate Tests, as shown below.
func ApiCall(context.Context, string) (int, error) {
    return 42, nil
}

func Example_apiCall() {
    // Because `// Output:` is omitted, this example won't actually be run.
    // Therefore, I suggest keeping examples as concise as possible.
    var output int
    var err error
    output, err = ApiCall(context.Background(), os.Getenv("API_KEY"))
    fmt.Println(output, err)
}

func Test_ApiCall(t *testing.T) {
    os.Setenv("API_KEY", "123") // The environment only works while the program is running; that is, it will disappear after the program stops.
    if os.Getenv("API_KEY") == "" {
        fmt.Printf("skip %q. since API_KEY is empty", t.Name())
        return
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    output, err := ApiCall(ctx, os.Getenv("API_KEY"))
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    if output != 42 {
        t.Fatalf("expected:%d, acutal:%d", 42, output)
    }
}

go-playground
